# Dynamically create a <mat-error> component and have it be projected into the parent <mat-form-field> component properly

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

Using the `ComponentFactoryResolver` to dynamically create a component is straight forward, but it doesn't seem to project the created component into the parent when I try and do this for the Angular Material `<mat-error>` component within a `<mat-form-field>`.  I've been using Netanel Basal's [example](https://netbasal.com/make-your-angular-forms-error-messages-magically-appear-1e32350b7fa5) with Bootstrap components, which works great for generating form control errors, but due to the content projection used in Angular Material with `<mat-error>` I can't seem to get it to work for Angular Material v8.2.1.

Is it possible to dynamically create a `<mat-error>` in a `<mat-form-field>` and have it content project properly?

Comment: Got some code we can look at..?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? A `mat-form-field` only needs to have one `mat-error` -  it is simple to dynamically change the error content.

Comment: It'd be helpful to post a stackblitz and the version of @angular/material you're using....`MatFormField` has gone through some changes

Comment: @G.Tranter we didn't want to add the `mat-error` to every form field when it could be dynamically generated on demand.  We can absolutely have a `mat-error` and then apply a method `{{ getError('formGroup.formControl') }}`, and do a look up of the error message, but we'd be adding that method to every component and it just adds template bloat.

Comment: @joh04667 we're using Angular Material v8.2.1

Comment: @ShyAgam the code is the Netanel Basal StackBlitz example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/netanel-control-er) from the indicated article, but replacing the `ControlErrorComponent` or dynamically loading the `mat-error` component and have it content project properly.

Comment: @mtpultz how is dynamically adding `<mat-error>{{ getError('formGroup.formControl') }}</mat-error>` to `<mat-form-field>` better than dynamically adding `<span>{{ getError('formGroup.formControl') }}</span>` to `<mat-error>`?

Comment: @G.Tranter that example you're referencing is what I was saying I would need to add manually to each form control if I can't do it dynamically.

Comment: @mt@mtpultz If you have that many form fields and the rules for computing errors are consistent across them then you can just create your own component based on `mat-form-field` which handles the error handling.

Comment: you can "simulate" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933635/how-to-dynamically-add-a-mat-error-to-a-mat-input-field/55936475#55936475. I just updated to take account "blur"

Comment: There is an related [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933635/how-to-dynamically-add-a-mat-error-to-a-mat-input-field/75936653#75936653).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've tried this before - [MatFormField](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/form-field/form-field.ts#L273) picks up `MatError`s via `ContentChildren`. Since it's content projection, dynamically adding or removing elements like `MatError` doesn't work -- the content template is compiled and handled differently than other templates.

You mentioned in a comment that you're trying to handle consistent error messaging across templates...why not add a `directive` *to* the `<mat-error>` element that controls the error messaging based on the parent control's form validation state?

If you're looking to control templates, though, you can't use a directive. You can, however, create a component and *use* it like a directive:

Create new file `mat-error-messages.component.ts`, this is full code of file:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {MatFormField, MatFormFieldControl} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatInput} from '@angular/material/input';

@Component({
    selector: '[matErrorMessages]',
    template: '{{ error }}'
})
export class MatErrorMessagesComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    public error = '';
    private inputRef: MatFormFieldControl<MatInput>;

    constructor(private _inj: Injector) {
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // grab reference to MatFormField directive, where form control is accessible.
        const container = this._inj.get(MatFormField);
        this.inputRef = container._control;

        // sub to the control's status stream
        this.inputRef.ngControl.statusChanges.subscribe(this.updateErrors);
    }


    private updateErrors = (state: 'VALID' | 'INVALID'): void => {
        if (state === 'INVALID') {
            // active errors on the FormControl
            const controlErrors = this.inputRef.ngControl.errors;

            // just grab one error
            const firstError = Object.keys(controlErrors)[0];

            if (firstError === 'required')
                {this.error = 'This field is required.';}

            if (firstError === 'minlength')
                {this.error = 'This field should be longer.';}

            if (firstError === 'error from my own custom validator')
                {this.error = 'You get the point.';}
            // .....
        }
    };
}
```

then in template....

```
<mat-error matErrorMessages></mat-error>
```

This way, you let the `MatFormField` control the presence of the `MatError` as it's supposed to do, but you control the *content* of the error element in a localized, clean way.

stackblitz of the above: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjkfft

You have to dig in to the Material components' private members, which is questionable practice, and can break with library updates, but it works.

I actually have a repo for this type of error messaging that was written for a much older version of @angular/material, but I was also able to get a hold of the `Validator` itself for better error messaging, and was injecting a whole list of custom validators/errors for that validator into the module: https://github.com/joh04667/material-error-messages

Comment: So if I were to use a directive on the `mat-error` instead would I be able to access the `FormControl` to determine the error?  I want to stay away from doing something like `<mat-error>{{ getErrorMessage('formControlName') }}</mat-error>` and would be quite happy to have `<mat-error appErrorMessage></mat-error>` for each since it would avoid having a `getError` method being added to every component.  I kind of thought it might not be possible due to content projection esp after experimenting with it, but was hoping I was wrong, but the directive would good alternative.

Comment: Yup! In the code above, the injector grabs the MatFormField. On that MatFormField, the `FormControl` is the MatFormField._control.ngControl. Come to think of it, you may just be able to inject `FormControl` directly to get the reference, but I'm not able to test that at the moment.

Comment: Ok, I checked, you can't inject a FormControl or NgControl. However, I did get this stackblitz up and running: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjkfft.  Check out the repo I linked to see how to get custom `Validators` and rich data into the errors!

Comment: This way not work when submit form, it only work when change value of input!

Comment: Yes, you would need an event to run change detection on form controls before submitting a form. Unblurred inputs are valid by default. You can do this via the FormGroup.

Answer (score 2):

this just another alternative solution ,inspired by [**`ngx-valdemort`**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8dvid) to create a component for handle validation error message of control , it is just required to be child in the formGroup body and pass the name of the form control and it 's not restricted to angular material component.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'error-summary',
  templateUrl: './error-summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error-summary.component.css']
})
export class ErrorSummaryComponent  {

  @Input() control:string;

  @Input() visible:any;

  constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) { }

  get form():FormGroup {
    return this.controlContainer.control  as FormGroup;
  }

  get formControl() :AbstractControl{
    return this.form.get(this.control) as AbstractControl;
  }

  get isNotValid() {
    return this.formControl.invalid && (this.formControl.touched || this.formControl.dirty)
  }

}
```

template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="isNotValid"  >
  <ng-container *ngIf="formControl.hasError('required')"> this is required </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="formControl.hasError('email')">this not valid email format</ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="formControl.hasError('maxlength')">max ...</ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="formControl.hasError('minlength')">min ...</ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

and can be use like this

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">

  <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter your email" formControlName="email">
  </mat-form-field>
    <error-summary control="email" ></error-summary>

  ...

</form>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8dvid)

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer worked only when user interacts with the field. What if user never interacts with fields and directly tries to submit the form?

So here i will improve answer:

> Note: here i used [transloco](https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/) to translate texts, you can remove it
> and use your way to do that.

**1 -** Create new file `mat-error-messages.component.ts` with this code:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {MatFormField, MatFormFieldControl} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatInput} from '@angular/material/input';
import {TranslocoService} from '@ngneat/transloco';

@Component({
    selector: '[matErrorMessages]',
    template: '{{ error }}'
})
export class MatErrorMessagesComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    public error = '';
    private inputRef: MatFormFieldControl<MatInput>;

    constructor(
        private _inj: Injector,
        private _translocoService: TranslocoService
    ) {
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // grab reference to MatFormField directive, where form control is accessible.
        const container = this._inj.get(MatFormField);
        this.inputRef = container._control;

        // sub to the control's status stream
        this.inputRef.ngControl.statusChanges.subscribe(this.updateErrors);
    }


    private updateErrors = (state: 'VALID' | 'INVALID'): void => {
        if (state === 'INVALID') {
            // active errors on the FormControl
            const controlErrors = this.inputRef.ngControl.errors;
            // just grab one error
            const firstError = Object.keys(controlErrors)[0];
            const varList = Object.values(controlErrors)[0]; // variables of error
            switch (firstError) {
                case 'required':
                case 'email':
                case 'minlength':
                case 'maxlength':
                case 'pattern':
                    this.error = this._translocoService.translate(`validation.${ firstError }`, varList);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

2- In your submit function, at first of function should be like this:

```
handleSubmit(): void {
    if (this.formGroup.invalid) {
      Object.keys(this.formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
        const value: AbstractControl = this.formGroup.get(key);
        if (value instanceof FormGroup) {
          value.markAsDirty();
          value.markAllAsTouched();
          value.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true });
        } else {
          value.markAsDirty();
          value.markAsTouched();
          value.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true });
        }
      });
      return;
    }

    ................ your code
}
```

> Note: To avoid code duplication you can set it in function in other
> class and just call it with pass `formGroup` variable.

3- In all `mat-form-field` of forms add:

```
<mat-error matErrorMessages></mat-error>
```

like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
   <textarea matInput [formControlName]="'name'"></textarea>
   <mat-error matErrorMessages></mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

4- My translation texts:

```
{
    "validation": {
        "required" : "This field is required.",
        "email": "Please enter a valid email address.",
        "pattern": "This value has syntax error.",
        "minlength": "Please enter at least {{requiredLength}} characters, you have entered only {{actualLength}}.",
        "maxlength": "Please enter no more than {{requiredLength}} characters, you have entered only {{actualLength}}."
    }
}
```